# Using Leader Line on VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I am trying to download and run [Leader Line](https://github.com/anseki/leader-line/) on VueJS and had a few issues that were open online but with no absolute solution.

I have installed leader-line via npm - `npm install leader-line`

Then this is my code for the vuejs file.

HTML:

```
<div id="start">start</div>
<div id="end">end</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
import LeaderLine from 'leader-line'
const myLine = new LeaderLine(
     document.getElementById('start'),
     document.getElementById('end')
);
```

And I simply got this error message:

```
TypeError: leader_line__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9___default.a is not a constructor
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated, thank you!

Comment: See https://github.com/anseki/leader-line/issues/8#issuecomment-370147614

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Leader Line](https://github.com/anseki/leader-line/) package cannot be imported as discussed in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/anseki/leader-line/issues/8#issuecomment-370147614).

An updated package is available here: [Leader Line New](https://github.com/II-alex-II/leader-line-new). This package is just the **anseki** version with imports and types.

The javascript in your case looks like this:

```js
import LeaderLine from 'leader-line-new';
const myLine = new LeaderLine(
     document.getElementById('start'),
     document.getElementById('end')
);
```